# Node.js - Floating point calculation - Intl.NumberFormat vs decimal.js library

Tags: javascript, node.js, floating-point, decimal.js

I would like to understand the difference between [Intl.NumberFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) and [decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js/v/3.0.0) library.

if Intl.NumberFormat is capable of handling the currency calculations then where does [decimal.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/decimal.js/v/3.0.0) library stand and what benefit it does provider over `Intl.NumberFormat`

This is specifically for Node.js (Probably 14+)

Answer (score 1):

I have some experience using both of these libraries, so I will do my best to explain each of them:

**Intl.NumberFormat and decimal.js** are both libraries in JavaScript that can be used to format and manipulate numbers. However, while they are similar in some ways, they are very different in others.

**Intl.NumberFormat is a built-in JavaScript library that provides localization support for number formatting, including decimal and grouping separators, decimal precision, and currency formatting. It is widely used to format numbers based on a user's language and region.**

**Decimal.js is a third-party library that provides arbitrary-precision decimal arithmetic for JavaScript. It allows for precise calculations with decimal numbers, which are often required in financial and scientific applications where rounding errors can have significant consequences.**

Although Intl.NumberFormat can handle basic currency formatting, it may not be suitable for all use cases. For example, it may not handle more complex currency formatting requirements, such as rounding rules or multiple currencies in the same document. In such cases, decimal.js can provide more precise and flexible currency handling capabilities.

I hope this answered your question!

Comment: Its pretty clear to me that Intl.NumberFormat is primarily for formatting purpose, but I would like to understand the benefits of decimal.js library. Generic statement that its better in terms of precision is fine but do you have any example to describe on precise calculation. My requirement is very much around currency calculation. And I did see Intl.Number format has min and max precision as well.

Answer (score 0):

I agree to Promaster's answer, it's also worth noting that using the decimal.js library may have performance implications, as it is a third-party library that requires additional processing overhead compared to the built-in Intl.NumberFormat library. Therefore, you should consider the specific requirements of your application when deciding whether to use decimal.js or Intl.NumberFormat.

The main benefit of using the decimal.js library over Intl.NumberFormat is the ability to perform precise mathematical operations on decimal numbers. If your application requires this level of precision, then decimal.js may be a better choice. However, if your application only requires formatting numbers for display, then Intl.NumberFormat may be sufficient.